# SQL Server Where clause with Case Checking null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

So basically performing a name search on first and last name. The first name search parameter is not required, so I need a case statement in the where clause. However, the field first name in the table I'm searching can also be null.

And the problem is in SQL Server to check for a `null` you must use is null or is not null and I can't seem to use that with a case. The regex `%` doesn't cover null values.

Is this possible in one query or will this need to be two separate queries?

Here is essentially what it looks like:

```
select *
from table
where first_name like case
                       when @pFirstName is not null then @pFirstName
                       when @pFirstName is null then '%' end
and last_name = @pLastName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Boolean logic :

```
WHERE ( (@pFirstName IS NOT NULL AND first_name = @pFirstName) OR
        (@pFirstName IS NULL)
      ) AND (last_name = @pLastName);
```

However, the first logic you can evaluate also :

```
(@pFirstName IS NULL OR first_name = @pFirstName)
```

By using that your query would be [SARGable](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222053424/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: Your solution worked. I Had not realized I could have parameters in the where clause. Thanks!

Comment: SARGable yes, but not in combination with an OR. And you can't rely just on syntax to determine if a query will use an index or not, or if it will use it efficiently or not. Not to mention we don't even know if he has an index or not. And will it be used in a query where he's selecting `*` ? I'm sorry but I don't agree with this being the **best** answer.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu. . . I agree with lack of information that i provided with answer, i don't want to go with `SARGable` or `NON-SARGable` topic or any kind of performance issues topic. This only address the actual issue of `OP`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I agree. I have absolutely no issue with the solution, but I do think that if you mentioned SARGability in your answer, then you should ensure that it is indeed valid. All answers an SO, and especially accepted ones should have as close to 100% accurate information as possible, so that future readers get the correct information from the start. That is why I added my comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `ISNULL()` in order to handle passing of one argument or not.

I don't really recommend using this in a query, but you can do something like:

```
select *
from table
where first_name = ISNULL(@pFirstName, first_name)
    and last_name = @pLastName;
```

However, a better version would be:

```
select         /* do you really need all (*) the columns? */
    column_1
    , column_2
    , column_3 
from table
where first_name = ISNULL(@pFirstName, first_name)
    and last_name = @pLastName
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

I'm adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so that your query performs optimally (as far as it can in this form), by recalculating row estimates in case the `@pFirstName` parameter is not provided.

Ideally you would treat passing a parameter with a IF:

```
IF @pFirstName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        select
            column_1
            , column_2
            , column_3 
        from table
        where first_name = @pFirstName
            and last_name = @pLastName;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select
            column_1
            , column_2
            , column_3 
        from table
        where last_name = @pLastName;
     END
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select *
from table
where (@pFirstName is null or first_name = @pFirstName)
  and last_name = @pLastName;
```

If `@pFirstName` is null, then `(@pFirstName is null or first_name = @pFirstName)` evaluates to true. If `@pFirstName` is not null, then the whole expression will be true whenever `first_name = @pFirstName` is true.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this can do it

```
select *
from   table
where  (first_name is null or first_name = @pFirstName)
and    last_name = @pLastName
```

if you need a `like` it will look more like this

```
select *
from   table
where  (first_name is null or first_name like '%' + @pFirstName + '%')
and    last_name like '%' + @pLastName + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this one:

```
select * from table where last_name = @pLastName and 
    (@pFirstName is null or first_name = @pFirstName)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...WHERE  (first_name like @pFirstName OR @pFirstName IS NULL) 
            AND last_name = @pLastName
```